# How to use Ajax , JQuery in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am using Ajax and jQuery in yii.

I have a view its url is like that.

`http://localhost/UnderstandQuran/index.php?r=Verse/topicverse&topic_id=1`

Now there are some radio buttons group. When i click on it, it will be called by jquery.

## My View Code.

```
<?php $i= 0;
foreach($data->verse_lang as $vtlanguage) {
$i = $i+1 ;
if($i === 1) { ?>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo "tran".$data->id ?>" class="translanguage" langid="<?php echo $vtlanguage['id']; ?>" verseid="<?php echo $data->id ?>" checked="checked"><?php echo $vtlanguage['language_name']; ?></input>
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo "tran".$data->id ?>" class="translanguage" langid="<?php echo $vtlanguage['id']; ?>" verseid="<?php echo $data->id ?>"><?php echo $vtlanguage['language_name']; ?></input>
<?php } } ?>
```

## My JQuery Code

```
$("input[type='radio'][class='translanguage']").click(function ()
{
    var siteUrl = document.URL;
    var verseid = $(this).attr("verseid");
    var langid = $(this).attr("langid");
    var vname = $(this).attr("name");

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: siteUrl + "/singleverse",
        data:
        {
            verseid: verseid,
            langid: langid
        },
        success: function (result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Through Ajax, i am sending it to the controller/Controller Method.

## My Controller Method

```
public function actionSingleverse()
{
    $verseid = $_POST['verseid'];
    $langid = $_POST['langid'];
    echo $verseid." ".$langid;
}
```

## My Question

Now through all of my code. It should be giving the alert box with two different integer value, but it is displaying all the html code of the page.
So how i can solve this issue.
I have checked in console.log, but gives 505 error.

My all this code is working fine when the above URL is like that.

`http://localhost/UnderstandQuran/index.php?r=Verse`

Please help me, what and where is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is't there problem with url? it seems to be 
`http://localhost/UnderstandQuran/index.php?r=Verse/topicverse&topic_id=1` in document.URL 
so siteUrl var in javascript is `http://localhost/UnderstandQuran/index.php?r=Verse/topicverse&topic_id=1/singleverse`

Comment: yes, there is a URL problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Paste your url in the following  format am sure it will work

```
  url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/controllername/singleverse',
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there will be some problem in this place

```
var siteUrl = document.URL;
```

The Site Url can also be got in javascript like this

```
var siteUrl = <?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl() ?>;
```

May be this could help you

Comment: Note: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) or at least quotes should probably be used in the 2nd snippet as JavaScript doesn't support [URLs as literals](http://jsconsole.com/?var%20siteUrl%20%3D%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FUnderstandQuran%2F%3B).